# How to make the textarea fill the whole column using min.css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a basic text reverser on https://shinkarom.github.io/reverser/ (the source code is https://github.com/shinkarom/reverser). For CSS framework I am using http://mincss.com.

The reverser is split into two columns. The left one has the textarea. The right one has the reversed text.

Unfortunately, the textarea is too small and doesn't fill the whole column. Giving it `width: 100%;height: 100%; box-sizing:border-box` solved the width problem, but the height is still too small.

As a workaround, I tried to give the textarea 25 rows, but it looked very ugly on a smaller browser window.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col c6">
  <textarea id="text" class="smooth" style="width: 100%;height: 100%; 
    box-sizing:border-box;resize:none"></textarea>
  </div>
 <div class="col c6">   
  <div id="result"> </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How to make the textarea fill the whole height?

Answer (score 2):

put `height:100vh` instead of 100% if you want the textarea to take full height of page. `height:100%` can't be applied unless your parent div has specified static height.

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col c6">
  <textarea id="text" class="smooth" style="width: 100%;height: 100vh; 
    box-sizing:border-box;resize:none"></textarea>
  </div>
 <div class="col c6">   
  <div id="result"> </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting 100vh makes the height too large so that scrollbars appear. It seems 100vh counts not to the bottom of the window but but as a specific number of pixels.

Comment: @shinkarom , that is because your <h1>The Text Reverser</h1> occupies some height, may be height:80vh will fit into the page.